# Limit of an expression to $e$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

[image]

Can you explain why its $e$?

I know limits like:

$$
(1+\frac{1}{x})^x \to e
$$

And similar limits.

But i dont understand how they got to $e$ there.

Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\frac{\sin\frac1{n^2}}{\cos\frac1n}n^2=\frac{\sin\frac1{n^2}}{\frac1{n^2}}\frac1{\cos\frac1n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot\frac11=1$$

Remember also that

$$\text{if}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty\;,\;\;\text{then}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{f(n)}\right)^{f(n)}=e$$

so now check with

$$\frac1{f(n)}=\frac{\sin\frac1{n^2}}{\cos\frac1n}=\frac1{\frac{\cos\frac1n}{\sin\frac1{n^2}}}\;\ldots$$

Comment: Got it. Now, how do you know that $f(n) \to \infty$ in our case? I cant see it.

Comment: Got it.  $cos 1/n \to 1, sin 1/n^2 \to 0$ therefore $f(n) \to 1/0 "=" \infty$

Comment: Well, that follows at once from continuity of the sine and cosine functions: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\frac1n=\cos0=1\;,\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\frac1{n^2}=\sin0=0$$

Comment: Yes, indeed you got it!

Answer (score 1):

The inside of the bracket goes to $e$ and the exponent goes to $1$ . A coupe of details needed here for you are: $\cos \frac{1}{n} \to 1$, and $n^2\cdot \sin^2(\frac{1}{n^2}) \to 1$.